Looking at Chrome dev tools network request timings only some of them show DNS lookup…why?
I’m trying to do some before and after analysis of using dns-prefetch and/or reconnect hints to see if it improves network requests timings.
I would expect to see DNS lookup in the timings of requests to the assets, API calls etc.  But I only see some DNS lookup timings for maybe like 7 out of 100 network requests.
I exported a HAR to save/view the details and many requests show “DNS time” as “Does not apply” or “0 ms”
Why is this the case?
(Note: We use different CDNs for our assets and our SPA)
I’ve also tried to go to chrome://net-internals/#dns to “Clear Host Cache”, but that didn’t seem to make a difference.
——-
Update:
Tried going to chrome://net-export to record detailed logs. And when using the viewer all entries under the DNS section showed a TTL of -1000.

Cache hit? It won't make another request if it's just got a result with a suitable TTL.

I’ve tried it after Clearing Host Cache using the chrome net-internals. Does that affect the TTL?

@pjc50 I tried clearing the host cache and recorded network logs and all DNS entries show -1000 TTL.
